# Exclude parameter with asterisks in Get-Childitem

Tags: powershell, get-childitem

I want to use Get-ChildItem Powershell method and pass a list to -Exclude parameter, but I want to use wildcards (like *$exclude* with single string) so that all files that only contain any of the excludes will be excluded. How can I do it?

I want to exclude from Get-ChildItem method return all files that only contain any of the excludes in their names.

Comment: What have you tried?  -exclude is a funny beast; you have to use it with -recurse or * in the path.

Answer (score 0):

I used Contains with a ! (not).  You can also use Regex. I also used ALL to get more than one match string. I made the list capital letters and then used ToUpper() to get both lower and uppercase to match. See code below

```
$excludeList = @("LOG", "CSV")

Get-ChildItem -Path "c:\temp\" `
   | where {![Linq.Enumerable]::Any([string[]]$excludeList,  [Func[string,bool]]{ param($excludeItem); return $_.Name.ToUpper().Contains($excludeItem) }) -eq $True} `
   | ForEach-Object {Write-Host $_.Name}
```

Using Regex

```
$excludeList = @("LOG", "CSV")
Get-ChildItem -Path "c:\temp\" `
   | where {![Linq.Enumerable]::Any([string[]]$excludeList,  [Func[string,bool]]{ param($excludeItem); return $_.Name.ToUpper() -match $excludeItem }) -eq $True} `
   | ForEach-Object {Write-Host $_.Name}
```